# How to implement accordion in pure js not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, accordion

I would like to know how to implement accordion in javascript.

Below accordion function is not working stating the error as
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null`

I got stuck please help and 
need to do following in javascript only.
I have updated the code below html, css and javscript code.

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="card"  class="accordioncontent" id="accordioncontent_js">
  <p>Implement Accordion in Pure JS</p>
</div>
<div class="card-title">
 <h5 class="accordionheader" @click=${this.handleToggle('js')}>JS</h5>
</div>

<div class="card"  class="accordioncontent" id="accordioncontent_ph">
  <p>Implement Accordion in Pure JS</p>
</div>
<div class="card-title">
 <h5 class="accordionheader" @click=${this.handleToggle('ph')}>PH</h5>
</div>
</div>
js
  handleToggle(xid){
    var aC = this.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll("accordioncontent");
    var sc= this.shadowRoot.getElementById("accordioncontent_" + xid)
    var i;
       for(i = 0; i < aC.length; i++){
          var OaC = aC[i];
             if(aC[i] != sc){
                OaC.classList.remove("show_Content")
             }
       }
        sc.classList.toggle("show_Content");
 }
css
.show_Content{
    padding:20px 0;
    display:block;
    border:1px solid #a3a3a3;
    border-top:none;
    animation:slow-down .5s ease
    }

@keyframes slow-down{
    from{padding:0;opacity:0}
    to{padding:20px 0;opacity:1}
    }
.show_Content:before{
    content:"";
    width:8px;
    top:-7px;
    left:50%;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    border-left:8px solid transparent;
    border-right:8px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:8px solid #fff
    }
```

Comment: Here's the first link that popped up on Google: [Pure Javascript Accordion](https://codepen.io/sureshrkm/pen/ZbzBpr)

Comment: @iuliu.net thanks for reply, yes i have seen that, I have updated my code in which got stuck.

Comment: You are passing the value `PH` to your click handler function, and append that to `accordioncontent_` to find an element by ID … only there is no such element. `accordioncontent_PH` and `accordioncontent_ph` are two different things.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.active, .accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc; 
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Accordion</h2>

<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<script>
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```